# Shiny output not rendering in rmarkdown website

Tags: r, iframe, shiny, r-markdown

We use rmarkdowns to make websites, at this point with static html.  However, we'd like to add shiny content.  Yet, the only way I've figured out how to do this is with an iframe (https://datasciencegenie.com/how-to-embed-a-shiny-app-on-website/).  When I try to code the shiny app either directly in the rmarkdown chunk or refer to it with `shinyAppDir` I get this error:

```
Error: path for html_dependency not provided
```

I've tried changing the runtime of the individual rmd but that fails with the same error.

Is there a way to imbed shiny apps in rmarkdown website without separately publishing them and referring to them as iframes?

Here's a github repo with a minimally repeatable example.  In this case I don't get the same error, but the shiny will not render in the website.

https://github.com/bpbraun/shiny-doesnt-work-in-website

Comment: `runtime: shiny` in the yaml header

Comment: For an individual rmd that works, but not when you build the website

Comment: You asked "Is there a way to imbed shiny apps in rmarkdown website without separately publishing them" With RMarkdown you get a standalone HTML file that can be hosted locally on your computer or on a network, but your HTML page has to be rendered from Rmarkdown, Or you use Shiny, and that uses a server/client model, Shiny renders user input, meaning it serves responses, so when you say `without publishing them`, are you you wanting a webpage without being on a server?

Comment: I understand that they need to be on a server.  What I mean is in reference to using the iframe method where you publish the app separately from the rmarkdown rendered website; you then make a html reference to the app in the rmarkdown.  This is a pretty burdensome solution though because you have to separately publish all the apps.

Answer (score 1):

With Rmarkdown websites, you need 2 files located in the same directory. This is why I love Rmarkdown and Shiny, they allow you so much creative control.

`index.Rmd`

````
---
title: ""
runtime: shiny
---


```{r echo = FALSE}

library(shiny)
library(networkD3)
library(dplyr)

shinyApp(
ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId = "school",
                label   = "School",
                choices =  c("alpha", "echo")),
    
    sankeyNetworkOutput("diagram")
),

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    dat <- data.frame(schname = c("alpha", "alpha", "alpha", "echo"),
                      next_schname = c("bravo", "charlie", "delta", "foxtrot"),
                      count = c(1, 5, 3, 4))
    
    links <- data.frame(source = dat$schname,
                        target = dat$next_schname,
                        value  = dat$count)
    nodes <- data.frame(name = c(as.character(links$source),
                                 as.character(links$target)) %>%
                            unique)
    
    links$IDsource <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1
    links$IDtarget <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1
    
    links2 <-reactive({
        links %>%
            filter(source == input$school)
    })
    
    
    output$diagram <- renderSankeyNetwork({
        sankeyNetwork(
            Links = links2(),
            Nodes = nodes,
            Source = "IDsource",
            Target = "IDtarget",
            Value = "value",
            NodeID = "name",
            sinksRight = FALSE
        )
    })
}

)
````

and "*_site.yml*", which is the YAML file that helps Rmarkdown render a navbar and gives it a webpage feel and functionality.

`_site.yml`

```
name: ""                                # CHANGE HERE 
output_dir: "."
navbar:
  title: ""                             # CHANGE HERE 
  type: inverse
  right:
    - text: "Contact me"
      icon: fa-envelope-o
      href: mailto:email@gmail.com               # CHANGE HERE 
    - text: "GitHub"
      icon: fa-github
      href: https://github.com/ 
    - text: "Stackoverflow"
      icon: fa-stack-overflow
      href: https://stackoverflow.com/users/
    - text: "Youtube"
      icon: fa-youtube
      href: https://www.youtube.com/channel/
    - text: "Instagram"
      icon: fa-instagram
      href: https://www.instagram.com/
    - text: "Twitter"
      icon: fa-twitter
      href: https://twitter.com/
output: html_document
```

Notice the Shiny code in the `index.Rmd` in the R chunk

`Shiny code`

```
library(shiny)
library(networkD3)
library(dplyr)

shinyApp(
ui <- fluidPage(
    selectInput(inputId = "school",
                label   = "School",
                choices =  c("alpha", "echo")),
    
    sankeyNetworkOutput("diagram")
),

server <- function(input, output) {
    
    dat <- data.frame(schname = c("alpha", "alpha", "alpha", "echo"),
                      next_schname = c("bravo", "charlie", "delta", "foxtrot"),
                      count = c(1, 5, 3, 4))
    
    links <- data.frame(source = dat$schname,
                        target = dat$next_schname,
                        value  = dat$count)
    nodes <- data.frame(name = c(as.character(links$source),
                                 as.character(links$target)) %>%
                            unique)
    
    links$IDsource <- match(links$source, nodes$name) - 1
    links$IDtarget <- match(links$target, nodes$name) - 1
    
    links2 <-reactive({
        links %>%
            filter(source == input$school)
    })
    
    
    output$diagram <- renderSankeyNetwork({
        sankeyNetwork(
            Links = links2(),
            Nodes = nodes,
            Source = "IDsource",
            Target = "IDtarget",
            Value = "value",
            NodeID = "name",
            sinksRight = FALSE
        )
    })
}

)
```

This renders me a shiny app of the Rmardown file, creating a webpage/webapp hybrid

[image]

Comment: The iframe method works, but it’s per burdensome. I need to make each app separately and publish them. I want to write the shiny code as part if a chunk or reference it within a chunk.

Comment: I updated my answer after your clarification

Comment: I'm talking about it in a website built using rmarkdown like here: https://rmarkdown.rstudio.com/lesson-13.html

Comment: updated my answer again, this does render it to a shiny app, notice the 127.0.0.1, but it is of the .Rmarkdown file, which is your website

Comment: Do you have this running locally or published somewhere?  What are you using to build the website?

Comment: I just created it, as you requested it, I could host it and link it if you  Mark my answer as correct.

Comment: Perhaps I misunderstand the question, but I think @BenG wants to host a Shiny app on internet without a Shiny server, which is of course not possible.

Comment: Right that is of course not the question.  And I know how to run the app, I'll update the question so it's more clear.

Comment: Updated, maybe this will make more sense now.